# Soft handover in Bluetooth networks

Tags: bluetooth

Hii all

Can anybody tell me the soft handover algo in BT networks, i mean the seamless connection??
Please share your views and code if some one have,

Answer (score 1):

There's no standardised roaming or handover in Bluetooth networks: they're intended to be personal area networks, not wide area networks with multiple base stations.